# Restoring deleted picture on canvas in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a program where I make use of a check button to delete and recover a background image in python tkinter. I got the deleting part. Can someone help with the recovering part? I want to recover the image on clicking the check button.

Comment: Can you please include some sample code as well as a few of the solutions you have tried?

Comment: Recover the image the same way you create the image at the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same with your background image as I have done with the `hi` variable.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar()


def test():
    if var.get():
        hi.grid_remove()
    else:
        hi.grid(column=0, row=1)


hi = tk.Label(text="hi")
hi.grid(column=0, row=1)

c_b = tk.Checkbutton(text="Check", variable=var, command=test)
c_b.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**Note:** Don't use `destroy()`. Use `grid.remove` or `grid.forget()` instead, otherwise your image won't be recovered.

I prefer using `grid.remove`, because if you need to do some change to a widget after making it disappear. Then to get it back `grid.forget` also won't work properly.